# Error : on the way Controllers/HelloWorldControllers.cs in ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to go to the following page in the tutorial:

https://localhost:44336/HelloWorld/Welcome

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC web application project and added a controller called `HelloWorldController` in the `Controllers` folder and used the following commands instead of the previous ones.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET : /HelloWorld/
        public string Index()
        {
            return "This is my default action...";
        }

        //
        // GET : /HelloWorld/Welcome/
        private string Welcome()
        {
            return "This is the Welcome action method...";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that it opens the following page:

```
https://localhost:44336/HelloWorld
```

But it does not open the following page:

```
https://localhost:44336/HelloWorld/Welcome
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `Welcome` is `private`:

Modify it to `public`:

```
public string Welcome()
{
    return "This is the Welcome action method...";
}
```

About the diffence of them you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Your action shouldn't be private when they are webpages. You should make them public